# root requirement on removal of module with composer

Tags: php, magento, composer-php, magento-1.9

when i am trying to remove the magento Extension in composer. I am getting following error though the Extension is successfully removing but i don't understand how to remove this error? OR why this error is coming at the time removing the Extension?

Dependency "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.

Any help will be extremely appreciated

thanks